# RestApi Query not grabbing the right emails based on DateTimeReceived

Tags: powershell, outlook-restapi

Everyday I get an email with an attachment that I want to download to my computer. I'm using Powershell to query for emails for today.

```
  ## Get all messages that have attachments where received date is greater than $date  
    $messageQuery = "" + $url + "?`$select=Id&`$filter=HasAttachments eq true and Subject eq 'FW: Time Detail' and DateTimeReceived ge 2018-11-14"
    $messages = Invoke-RestMethod $messageQuery -Credential $cred
```

This should give me all emails with subject 'FW: Time Detail with attachment received today. However I'm getting emails from yesterday. I tried a few things but I'm not getting the results that I'm specifying in the query.

Comment: Firstly, `2018-11-14` probably means `2018-11-14 00:00:00` but maybe not - you should check. Secondly perhaps one of the times is UTC and not local

Comment: yeah is UTC time. thanks!